# In React Native, how can you make changes to a local library from within your main project without having to compile the former

Tags: typescript, react-native, dependencies, shared-libraries

### The setup:

```
./company/MyApp  
./company/MyLibrary
```

### The desired workflow would be:

- Working on `MyApp` using e.g. VSCode
- Having `MyLibrary` as dependency to `MyApp`
- Make a change to `MyLibrary` without having to recompile
- Make a change to `MyLibrary` without needing any services that detect this change
- `MyApp` bundles correctly using `Metro`
- Making changes to `MyLibrary` whilst the app is running will hot reload the app

### What I have tried so far:

#### Using `yarn link` or `npm link`:

- cannot confirm that symlinked dependency is referenced from within the project by looking at the `node_modules` directory
- read that `Metro` bundler doesn't recognise symlinks (unconfirmed)
- stopped trying at this point, but can imagine that the dependency would still need to be compiled before changes are available to `MyApp`

#### Using [WML](https://github.com/wix/wml)

Works, but is cumbersome.
Installation:

- Install [watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#buildinstall)
- Install wml globally using `yarn global add wml`
- Run `watchman watch /Users/[your username]/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/wml/src`(or wherever `wml` is installed
- Run `wml add ~/my-package ~/main-project/node_modules/my-package`
- Run `wml start`

Workflow:

- Run `cd company/MyApp`
- Run `wml start`
- Run `yarn android:run` (or whatever your platform and script name is)
- Make changes to `MyLib`
- Run `(cd ../MyLibrary && tsc)`
- The app hot reloads with the latest changes from `MyLib`

However, this workflow doesn't fulfil several desired requirements:

- Make a change to `MyLibrary` without having to recompile
- Make a change to `MyLibrary` without needing any services that detect this change

## Question:

How can you make changes to a local library from within your main project without having to compile the former or run any services that detect this change?